# How do i pass this to SetTimeout() function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
  var workViewer = {
    container: document.documentElement,
    popup: document.querySelector('.avgrund-popup'),
    cover: document.querySelector('.avgrund-cover'),

    init: function () {
        this.addClass(this.container, 'avgrund-ready');
        window.avgrund = {
            activate: this.activate,
            deactivate: this.deactivate,
            disableBlur: this.disableBlur
        };
    },
    activateModal: function (state) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.parent.removeClass(popup, 'no-transition'); //this line
            this.parent.addClass(this.container, 'avgrund-active');  //this line
        }, 0);
    },


    removeClass: function (element, name) {
        element.className = element.className.replace(name, '');
    }
};


module.exports = workViewer;
```

I want to pass *this* into setTimeout function, whats the right way to do it?

This is my first post, please let me know if i can improve it in any way

Comment: `var that = this; function() { that.parent...`

Comment: Thank you! this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two major ways. The first is saving a reference to `this` and using it instead:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
  self.parent.removeClass(popup, 'no-transition');
  self.parent.addClass(self.container, 'avgrund-active');
}, 0);
```

The other is to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a new function with `this` bound to the given value.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.parent.removeClass(popup, 'no-transition');
  this.parent.addClass(this.container, 'avgrund-active');
}.bind(this), 0);
```

If you're running in an environment that supports them, you can also use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.parent.removeClass(popup, 'no-transition');
  this.parent.addClass(this.container, 'avgrund-active');
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). It creates function which is bounded to the given context:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    this.parent.removeClass(popup, 'no-transition'); //this line
    this.parent.addClass(this.container, 'avgrund-active');  //this line
}.bind(this), 0);
```